# JSON schema anyOf validation based on one of properties

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to validate an array of objects based on the value of one of the properties. So where I have a JSON object like:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "otherProperty": "bar"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo2",
            "otherProperty2": "baz",
            "otherProperty3": "baz2"
        },
        {
            "name": "imInvalid"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to say that

1. items can contain anyOf objects where name can be "foo" or "foo2"
2. if it's "foo" then the only valid other property (required) is
   "otherProperty"
3. if the name is "foo2" then the only valid other
   properties are "otherProperty2" and "otherProperty3" both required
4. No other value for "name" than "foo" and "foo2" is valid
5. The objects themselves are optional in the items array, and some might be repeated.

I've tried all kinds of things but I can't seem to get a failure when I validate. For example, the name "imInvalid" should be causing a validation error. This is my latest iteration of the schema. What am I missing?

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["items"],
    "properties": {
        "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "anyOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "required": ["name", "otherProperty"],
                            "additionalProperties": false,
                            "properties": {
                                "otherProperty": { "type": "string" },
                                "name": { "enum": [ "foo" ] }
                            }
                        },{
                            "type": "object",
                            "required": ["name", "otherProperty2", "otherProperty3" ],
                            "additionalProperties": false,
                            "properties": {
                                "otherProperty2": { "type": "string" },
                                "otherProperty3": { "type": "string" },
                                "name": { "enum": [ "foo2" ] }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you're nesting name and other property inside name.

Comment: If you feel like writing an answer showing the correct way and it validates on http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com that would be great - as I said I've tried a lot of different things over the last couple of days without luck. Above is just the most recent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You've got the basic idea of using enum to separate what's matching, but there are a couple of mistakes here:

- Json schema arrays don't have `properties`, they have `items`.
- Within those properties you're defining `name` as an attribute that then holds other json schema objects.
- In the second branch of your schema you defined `otherProperty3` but in your sample that property is called `anotherProperty3`

Try this slightly modified version:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"type": "object",
"required": ["items"],
"properties": {
    "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "items": {
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": ["name", "otherProperty"],
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "otherProperty": { "type": "string" },
                        "name": { "enum": [ "foo" ] }
                    }
                },{
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": ["name", "otherProperty2", "anotherProperty3" ],
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "otherProperty2": { "type": "string" },
                        "anotherProperty3": { "type": "string" },
                        "name": { "enum": [ "foo2" ] }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it somehow possible to not duplicate `name` property in both "anyOf" schemas?

Comment: What is crazy about this solution, is it 100% failed unless you include the `required` list of properties for each object. JSON Schema is so unclear about this and that also makes no sense.